# <img> doesn't display on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, materialize

I have a navbar in my site which I am testing out on mobile. For some reason, the images I have as part of the navigation menu don't display on Chrome for Android. I don't have the issue when I use a different browser or when I view the site on my laptop. Unfortunately I don't have an iPhone to test on.

The site uses materialize.css.

Here's an example of a navigation menu image which isn't being displayed:

```
<div class="menu-container menu-column">
    <div class="menu-container menu-row">
        <div class="menu-container menu-item">
            <a href="/" class="waves-effect"> 
                <img id="id-home" class="image menu-1" src='/path/to/png/file.png'>
            </a>Home
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried using the devtools remote device debugger to see what was in the console, there are no error messages or 404's or anything. I've got no idea what to do!

Any help is appreciated. I can provide more info if needed. 
Thank you!

EDIT: I've added a snippet. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to load images into jsfiddle so it's not going to be exactly possible to reproduce the error. Again, it looks fine on my browser and in responsive mode. In Chrome for Android, the `<img>`'s disappear.

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/hermana/z2b9L1nv/26/

Comment: did you check in desktop browser with responsive mode ?

Comment: Providing a working code snippet or codepen link would help you and others to help  you.

Comment: @Alex it works in responsive mode, but not on the actual device.

Comment: @ellen upload a demo or share a snippet for checking more that issue

Comment: @Alex See update. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your file has no extension like .jpg or png, and also your class attribute values in the Image need a closing double quotation " so that src attribute will be separated from class value

Comment: sorry I changed the file path before making it public. My img does have an extension and a closing quote - that was a typo. I'll try to add a snippet to make the problem more clear